# phplibsec environmental variables with Net_SSH2::exec()

Tags: php, ssh, environment-variables, phpseclib

Are there any built-in methods to set environmental variables with phplibsec's `Net_SSH2` class?

For instance

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
// $ssh->setEnv('TEST=Hello');
echo $ssh->exec('echo $TEST');
?>
```

Comment: I don't think that's currently possible unfortunately. Per http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4254#section-6.4 you have to make a "req" channel request to do that and phpseclib doesn't do that atm. Give me a few days and I'll see if I can't add that functionality.

Comment: @neubert Awesome.  I wrote a simple workaround for Unix/Linux I can share if you can't get it to work.  It just modifies the exec() function to call `export` before the command and keeps track of environmental variables in a class property.  I assume this can be made to work on Windows based systems as well.